# Extremely low framerate (5 FPS) for high resolution webcam Aukey PC-W1

Tags: webcam, cheese, obs-studio, framerate

**Frame rate is only 5FPS@1920X1080 for Aukey PC-W1 although the webcam is capable of 30fps at that resolution.**

- product page http://test.aukey.com/products/1080p-webcam-pc-w1
- In some programs like VLC it allows me to set the FPS higher but even though set higher it is still showing at 5FPS in reality.
- In OBS it shows the FPS is locked and for each resolution is only one FPS option (1920x1080@5FPS, 1280x720@10FPS, 848x480@20FPS, 640x480@30FPS etc.) **That makes the webcam unusable for HD streaming.**
- My hardware other than the webcam is not causing the problem. My CPU usage is usually between 10-50%.
- In Cheese it's showing also at 5FPS.
- Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Thank you for any help.